# Java - Array <init> error

Tags: java, arrays, init

So, I have this class, that contains another class array, and in the constructor I want to make "n" and "nCod" equal 0.

```
public class ITable
{   
TableRow arr[];

class TableRow
{
    long n;
    int nCod;
    ICode cod;

}

ITable()
{
    arr = new TableRow[256];
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        arr[i].n = 0;
        arr[i].nCod = 0;
    }
}
}
```

When I run it, Eclipse console tells me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at jhuffman.def.ITable.<init>(ITable.java:21)
```

That line is:

```
arr[i].n = 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an array instance with `new TableRow[256]`, each of its elements are initialized to null.

Therefore, each element should be initialized before being accessed :

```
arr = new TableRow[256];
for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
{
    arr[i] = new TableRow (); // add this
    arr[i].n = 0;
    arr[i].nCod = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object array with no initial values, all the positions in the array will point to `null`. So, for example, `arr = new TableRow[3]` would initialize the array as `[null, null, null]`.

Since you did not store any `TableRow` objects into `arr`, when you access `arr[i]`, it returns `null` instead of a concrete object. If you try to access a field in `null` it will result in a `NullPointerException` as you have observed.

What you need to do is create the `TableRow` instances and place them into the array before you try to access them. Something like this:

```
arr = new TableRow[256];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = new TableRow();
    arr[i].n = 0;
    arr[i].nCode = 0;
}
```